# Remove lines from this image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Trying to remove those lines after stitching multiple images but these lines are just not going away

Tried morphological Transformations of opencv nothing worked. Any help would be great.[image]

Comment: Perhaps this can be fixed in the stitching algorithm itself? If this is not possible, could you post the PNG image instead of the JPG?

Comment: Why do you need the image in png.

Comment: JPEG is a lossy compression algorithm, PNG is lossless. This causes the pixel values to stay correct in a PNG image. I'd like to look at the correct values before proposing a solution.

Comment: Can you make the stitching program generate a PNG file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gaussian blurring for this. However, as you want to remove vertical lines use a m x 1 kernel as it would affect only the vertical lines and will not blur horizontally.

```
img = cv2.imread('vertical_noise.jpg')
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (11, 1), 0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: result]

You can increase the kernel size to completely remove the lines but the image will also get blurrier.

**EDIT**

Sorry for the extremely late edit. If you don't want to blur then I don't know how to remove the lines in the car. However, the lines outside the car can be removed. For this create a threshold using `cv2.threshold` with a high thresh value and then find contours on it. Then using `cv2.drawContours` the blank spaces in the threshold image can be filled which can be treated as a mask. Using `cv2.bitwise_and` obtain two images using that as a mask with a blank image and using its inverse as a mask along with the original image. Then combine then `cv2.bitwise_or`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('vertical_noise.jpg')
height, width, ch = img.shape
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (11, 1), 0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(thresh, cnts, -1, 0, 3)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=cv2.bitwise_not(thresh))
blank = np.ones((height, width, ch), np.uint8)*255
inv_res = cv2.bitwise_and(blank, blank, mask=thresh)
res = cv2.bitwise_or(res, inv_res)
cv2.imshow('image', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: After first]

[image: Second]

[image: Result]

Now if you want you can blur it a little for the lines inside the car.

Comment: but blurring will make image less sharper and it will not be visible properly, and that should not happen.